# Electron-forge makes my windows setup file that runs application but does not install it

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-forge

I've got an electron app set up using electron-forge. Once I make the desktop app using my windows machine, it generates a set up file that I can launch my app with. The problem is that it only launches the app and does not install it. Everytime I click on this setup file, it installs the app as if installing for the first time. This takes 8minutes to complete as I have a large amount of stored mp3 files.

I've tried running `electron-forge make` in the command line, but I'm not sure if I'm missing any other steps to make the file install. Here's my package.json in full:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "productName": "my app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my very cool app",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --color --ext .jsx,.js src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "atlanteavila",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
        ]
      },
      "electronPackagerConfig": {
        "packageManager": "yarn",
        "icon": "public/images/app.ico"
      },
      "electronWinstallerConfig": {
        "name": "my_app",
        "icon": "public/images/app.ico"
      },
      "electronInstallerDebian": {},
      "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
      "github_repository": {
        "owner": "atlanteavila",
        "name": "Atlante Avila"
      },
      "windowsStoreConfig": {
        "windowsStoreConfig": {
          "packageName": "myapp",
          "name": "My App"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.1.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nedb-promises": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to add something to the electronWinstallerConfig? Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Possibly something didn't install correctly; try deleting both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, and then doing `npm install`. 2. Does `electron-packager [pathToApp] [appName] --platform=win32 --arch=x64` create a good version of your app? (assuming 64 bit machine) For that matter does `electron [pathToApp]` give good results?

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before but had to just package the app with electron-forge package, then I ran the electron-winstaller on its own and it worked fine. Something's wrong with the electron-forge version or something... Thanks for replying to that!

Comment: Yeah `electron-forge` doesn't seem to be all it's touted to be and `electron-winstaller` seems more work than it's worth. Glad you got it working though. I'm just gonna do a self-extracting ZIP for my installer using 7zip.